# Solving 2nd Order ODE w/Laplace Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

I am having difficulty with this problem:

[image]
*Note: The Delta3(t) is the delta dirac function, also the answer in the image is WRONG.

**Attempt at solution :**

1. Let Laplace{y(t)}=Y
2. Take Laplace of LHS and RHS.
3. Solve for Y.
4. Take inverse Laplace of Y, giving me a function of y(t)= some function

Now, are my steps correct for this type of problem?

How do I write this answer as a Heaviside function, as posed in the question?

Comment: How is $\delta_{3}(t)$ defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the Laplace transform as
\begin{align}
f(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} \, y(t) \, dt
\end{align}
then for the differential equation
\begin{align}
y'' - 3 y' -4 y = -4 t + \delta(t),
\end{align}
where $y(0) = -2$ and $y'(0) = -1$ then
\begin{align}
s^{2} f(s) - y'(0) - s y(s) - 3s f(s) + 3 y(0) - 4 f(s) = - \frac{4}{s^{2}} + 1 
\end{align}
which simplifies to
\begin{align}
(s+1)(s-4) f(s) = 6 - 2s - \frac{4}{s^2}.
\end{align}
Solving for $f$ leads to
\begin{align}
f(s) &= \frac{6}{(s+1)(s-4)} - \frac{2 s}{(s+1)(s-4)} - \frac{4}{s^{2}(s+1)(s-4)} \\
&= \frac{6}{5} \left( \frac{1}{s-4} - \frac{1}{s+1} \right) - \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{s+1} + \frac{4}{s-4} \right) + \frac{1}{ s^2} - \frac{3}{4 s} + \frac{4}{5 (s+1)} - \frac{1}{20 (s-4)} \\
&= \frac{1}{s^{2}} - \frac{3}{4 s} - \frac{9}{20} \frac{1}{s-4} - \frac{4}{5} \frac{1}{s+1}.
\end{align}
Inversion provides 
\begin{align}
y(t) = t - \frac{3}{4} - \frac{4}{5} e^{-t} - \frac{9}{20} e^{4t}.
\end{align}

---

The fraction involving $s^{2} (s+1)(s-4)$ is separated as follows
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{s^{2}(s+1)(s-4)} &= \frac{a}{s^{2}} + \frac{b}{s} + \frac{c}{s+1} + \frac{d}{s-4} \\
&= \frac{a + b s}{s^{2}} + \frac{c}{s+1} + \frac{d}{s-4}.
\end{align}
Now 
\begin{align}
d &= \left.\frac{(s-4)}{s^2 (s+1)(s-4)}\right|_{s=4} = \frac{1}{80} \\
c &= \left. \frac{s+1}{s^2 (s+1)(s-4)} \right|_{s=-1} = - \frac{1}{5} \\
a &= \left. \frac{s^2}{s^2 (s+1)(s-4)} \right|_{s=0} = - \frac{1}{4} \\
b &= \frac{3}{16}
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{s^{2}(s+1)(s-4)} = - \frac{1}{s^{2}} + \frac{3}{16 \, s} - \frac{1}{5(s+1)} + \frac{1}{80 \, (s-4)}
\end{align}

Comment: I need it in the form of : the solution is y(t) = for 0<t<3 and y(t) = for t>0.

Also can you explain how you "expanded" 4/[s^2(s+1)(s-4)] into /s^2 - 3/4s + 4/5(s+1) - 1/20(s-4)

Comment: I need to the solution in the form posed in the question! Also, did you ignore the delta dirac function?

Comment: @Jessica In the standard case $\mathcal{L}\{ \delta(t) \} = 1$. What is to be worked out, based on whatever the definition, is that of $\delta_{3}(t)$. If this was to be defined then a modification of the solution can be made.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DiracDeltaFunction.aspx 

Also #26 on http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx

If you can also mention how to put my solution in the form asked in the question, that would be cool.

Comment: @Jessica How, in an explicit form, is $\delta_{3}(t)$ defined? Both links define $\delta(t), \delta(t-a)$, as was used in the solution presented.

Comment: That's all I have been told, I guess it's fine.

Comment: δ3(t) = e^(-3s)